# IOleWindow not working properly for IFileDialog?

Tags: c#, com, common-dialog

I'm working with some code that uses Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack to provide a C# wrapper of the Vista-style common dialogs (`IFileOpenDialog`, `IFileSaveDialog`). I'm wanting to add validation of the selected item in the `OnFileOk` event callback, and this is mostly working, but one aspect of it is to extract the HWND of the dialog to use as a parent for the message box that is shown. Microsoft provides documentation on how to do this:

> The calling process can use the window handle of the dialog itself as the parent of the UI. That handle can be obtained by first calling **IOleWindow::QueryInterface** and then calling **IOleWindow::GetWindow** with the handle as shown in this example.

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx)

I added a definition of the `IOleWindow` interface to the code:

```
[ComImport,
Guid(ShellIIDGuid.IOleWindow),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IOleWindow
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    void ContextSensitiveHelp(
        [In] bool fEnterMode);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    IntPtr GetWindow();
}

...

    internal const string IOleWindow = "00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046";
```

When I cast the `IFileDialog` passed into `OnFileOk` to `IOleWindow` (I haven't done that much work with COM interop recently, but this wraps a call to `QueryInterface` in the underlying COM world, right?), no error occurs and the `IOleWindow` reference is not `null`. But, when I call `GetWindow`, it seems to always return `IntPtr.Zero`. I have tried declaring the method with an `out` parameter instead of a return value, and get the same result: no error, but always `IntPtr.Zero`.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?? Am I doing nothing wrong, but just sometimes you can't get a window handle??

Comment: A usable IOleWindow declaration is [available here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,1edd0ef1d9063485).  Getting the methods is the wrong order is quite fatal.

Comment: Thanks very much! Trying it now.

Comment: As I'm sure you already knew, that was the problem exactly. If you feel like submitting an answer, even as little as "The order of methods in a COM interface is important, and the order in your IOleWindow declaration is wrong", I'll be happy to mark it as the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hans Passant's reply was on the nose. The order of methods in a COM interface is important, and I had the order wrong, simple as that. I got the order from documentation that was sorted alphabetically, and not from the actual IDL. :-P

Wrong order, for human eyes only:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-iolewindow

Right order, the actual IDL:

- https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/um/OleIdl.Idl#L577-L592

(I don't know who @tpn on GitHub is, this link may break but if it does then just look up `IOleWindow` in the file `OleIdl.idl` from the Windows SDK. :-) )